# Youtube videos in phonegap & android

Tags: android, youtube, cordova

I have a problem with playinh youtube videos in my app.

I have a page with embed video. When i tap on video, loader appears, everything is ok.

When loader dissapears, it should start playing. But in my application there is white screen appears.

On LogCat at this moment i can see this:

```
CordovaLog  showing Custom View
```

Problem fixed, by using plugin.

But, i have the same problem with VIMEO.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will help you to play a YouTube video in a Phonegap/Cordova app:
https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android

Comment: After all instructions, i have an error in LogCat

06-26 16:08:25.354: I/dalvikvm(29751): Could not find method com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent, referenced from method com.remcob00.plugins.youtube.YouTube.doSendIntent